# how to sum values inside for loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I try to get the summtion of the values inside a for loop but i couldn't do that 
like this code:

```
for($i=1;$i<=($value);$i++){
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $total=$max[1]+$max[2]+......+$max[$i];
        echo $total;
    }
}
```

When i press submit it gave me that there's a mistake in line 2 
that there is an unexpected '.'  and i couldn't find any solution to solve this problem
i hope that my problem is clear for you 
can any one help me please :)

Comment: can you post your code, from where you are these values are coming? probably some value mistake, . may be exist somewhere in the value.

Comment: Please note that arrays are [zero-indexed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering).  Also, if this is more than just a learning exercise - you have the [`array_sum`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) function at your disposal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ){
    $total = 0;
    for( $i = 1; $i <= $value; $i++ ){
      $total += $max[$i];
    }
    echo $total;
}
```

Comment: abo hassan, click the tick underneath the score on @immo's answer to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $total = 0;

    for($i=1; $i <= $value; $i++){

       $total += $max[$i]; 
    }

    echo $total;
}
```